# Hide web method services in webconfig or in deployment

Tags: .net, web-services, servicestack

I have a .net webservice solution with several webmethods exposed.
I need to deliver two deployments with this solution. One with all the methods exposed and other with some of those methods hidden.

Is there a way to hide certain methods easily so when I deploy them I can choose which ones to hide.

Maybe in webconfig or maybe some compilation/deployment options
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Restrict Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Restricting-Services) to both limit and hide Services in different scenarios, e.g you can hide Services from being visible by external Users by annotating your Request DTO's with:

```
[Restrict(VisibleInternalOnly = true)]
public class InternalAdmin { }
```

The `[Exclude]` attribute is an alternative attribute to hide Services from everyone and appearing in Metadata Services:

```
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]
public class Hidden {}
```

> As this is a popular scenario you can also use `[ExcludeMetadata]` instead.

So you could use `#def's` to create different builds with and without these attributes applied.

Otherwise these attributes can also be dynamically added at runtime using the dynamic attribute API, e.g:

```
typeof(Hidden)
    .AddAttributes(new ExcludeAttribute(Feature.Metadata));

new AppHost().Init();
```

Note attributes need to be added **before** `AppHost.Configure()` is run, so either in your AppHost constructor or before your AppHost is initialized as seen above.